# Polynomial of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $T : V \to V$ be a linear transformation. Let $U, W\subseteq V$ be $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$, such that $U\oplus W=V$. Let $q\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ be a polynomial. Given that $U$ is a sub-space of $\mbox{im }q(T)$, show that $\ker q(T)$ is a sub-space of $W$.

I tried to show the $U \cap \ker q(T)= \{0\}$.
Also, solving directly for the definitions. I also know that every $T$-invariant subspace is also $q(T)$-invariant. Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $q(T)|_U$ is surjective and $U$ is finite-dimensional, $q(T)|_U$ is bijective. Therefore, its kernel is $\{0\}$.

So, if $v\in\ker q(T)$, write $v$ as $u+w$, with $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. Now, $$T(u+w)=0\iff q(T)(u)=q(T)(-w).$$But $q(T)(-w)\in W$ (because $W$ is invariant) and $q(T)(-w)\in U$ (because $\operatorname{im}q(T)\subset U$). Therefore, $q(T)(-w)=0$, and so $q(T)(u)=0$. But $q(T)(u)=0\implies u=0$. Therefore, $v=0+w=w\in W$.

Comment: Oops. forgot to mention that $V$ is of finite dimension. Apologies.

Comment: Though, thank you very much. This is still helpful.

Comment: @user558964 I've edited my answer.

Comment: I am missing one thing, why is $q(T)$ surjective?

Comment: I see why $q(T)(W) \subseteq W$ but why does $q(T)(W) = W$?

Comment: @user558964 I've edited my answer. I wrote that $q(T)|_W$ is surjective, but what I meant was that $q(T)|_U$ is surjective. That's because $U\subset\operatorname{im}q(T)$.

Comment: Now it makes more sense, thank you Jose!